# Delay intput in Windows.Media.Audio.AudioGraph

Tags: c++, audio, uwp, c++-winrt

My goal is to be able to create `AudioGraph` with multiple input nodes that are connected to single `AudioSubmixNode` and be able to adjust timings between them.

Is it possible to delay input for single `IAudioInputNode2` or add some "delay" node after input node to achieve this goal?

If it is possible may it support negative delay?

I am currently working in c++ (winrt) but documentation or samples may be in any .net language as I did not found anything on the subject that could push me in correct direction.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create mutilple input nodes which connect the same AudioSubmixNode like this [Scenario4_Submix](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/AudioCreation/cs/AudioCreation/Scenario4_Submix.xaml.cs) does? If it is, it seems AudioGraph doesn't provide sucn api to delay files playback. But what about edit our files? Maybe you could try to edit your media and then mix them together by [Media compositions and editing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing).

Comment: If you are confused about how to convert C# codes to its equivalent in C++/WinRT, you could refer to this document: [Move to C++/WinRT from C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/move-to-winrt-from-csharp).

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT thanks for help. Yes it is similar to example you provided.  Application is using many different input node types not only files (devices, memory buffers) and it is "live". I know that it is possible to grab samples from input node, add some empty signal and put it back to audio pipeline, but I was looking for more elegant way of doing that (and maybe done already).

Comment: What does "maybe done already" mean? Do you mean you have achieved this function already?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Maybe there is a some component (property, node, etc.) that is doing this (adding delay) and I do not need to rewrite it myself.

Comment: Currently there is no such component or api to add delay effect, it seems that you need to achieve it manually.